# Hibernate CriteriaQuery<T> - any straight-forward code example?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I refer to ["Chapter 12. Criteria" in this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch12.html) manual.

They nicely explain that:

> The javax.persistence.criteria.**CriteriaBuilder** interface is the first
>   thing with which you need to become acquainted to begin using criteria
>   queries. Its role is that of a factory for all the individual pieces
>   of the criteria. You obtain a
>   javax.persistence.criteria.**CriteriaBuilder** instance by calling the
>   **getCriteriaBuilder** method of either
>   javax.persistence.**EntityManagerFactory** or
>   javax.persistence.**EntityManager**.

But, none says **where/how I get these EntityManager/EntityManagerFactory objects**. Sorry, it's just unclear.

I got the feeling it has to do with my Hibernate session, so here's my session code, let me know if/how to change it in order to get an `EntityManager` object so I can continue, I must be missing something here.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

import x.Debug;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final int            DEFAULT_TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT = 3;

    private static final HibernateUtil  m_instance;

    private final SessionFactory        m_session_factory;
    private final ServiceRegistry       m_service_registry;

    private Session                     m_session;

    static {
        m_instance = new HibernateUtil();
    }

    public static HibernateUtil get() {
        return m_instance;
    }

    public HibernateUtil() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        this.m_service_registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        this.m_session_factory = configuration
                .buildSessionFactory(this.m_service_registry);

        this.open_session();
    }

    public void open_session() {
        this.m_session = this.m_session_factory.openSession();
    }

    public void close_session() {
        this.m_session.close();
    }

    public Session get_session() {
        if (!this.m_session.isOpen())
            this.open_session();
        return this.m_session;
    }

    public void save_or_update_objects(final Object[] objects) {
        final Session session = this.get_session();

        try {
            // session.beginTransaction();
            session.getTransaction().setTimeout(DEFAULT_TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT);
            session.getTransaction().begin();

            for (final Object object : objects)
                session.saveOrUpdate(object);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public Object get_object(final Class<?> clazz, final Serializable id) {
        final Session session = this.get_session();

        if (Debug.DEBUG)
            session.clear();

        final Object ret = session.get(clazz, id);

        return ret;
    }
}
```

What I did find is how to simply, unrelated to Hibernate, build an `EntityManagerFactory` and here's the code:

```
final EntityManagerFactory entity_manager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnitName");
```

But I'm not sure it's OK, and regarding the "persistenceUnitName" - where did that come from?! Should I just invent a name?

The bottom line is that all I wanted is to search for objects with a certain criteria - Hibernate apparently made it really complicated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EntityManager` and `EntityManagerFactory` are interfaces that the provider implements.  In the case of Spring, you inject one (See [Spring ORM JPA](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa)).

In Hibernate, you can use the bootstrapping technique described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html_single/#setup-configuration-bootstrapping).  From that reference:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("manager1");
```

Comment: thanks though - can you refer to or paste a simple code example? Do I HAVE TO do all of this just for that? And, as you see in my original post I posted the whole `HibernateUtil` I'm using - how do I "inject" what I need into that (so for example it has an `EntityManager` object), while changing as little as possible code, and without Spring?

Comment: Saw the update. Well, seen that on the linked page yet it doesn't make sense, still. How is it related to my hibernate session? And what the heck is "manager1" - a string out of the blue? :)

Comment: Sorry, my Hibernate experience is quite old, several versions ago.  I struggled with these general concepts (API interface vs provider implementation) early-on also.  That seems to be one area that's not explained as well as it could be. I believe the name is just an arbitrary name given so the framework can keep track of separate managers (but don't quote me on that :-).

Comment: Hahaha, thanks Jim :) Let's hope a more clear answer comes, at the meanwhile I'm playing with HQL.. Shame they didn't make it as simple as Google App Engine's query for example. Yet again thank you sir!